# Exception raised while trying to delete file from Azure Data Lake

Tags: c#, .net, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

**Little Preface:** I am using `ADF` to archive(copy and delete) files from `Azure Data Lake Store` to `Azure Blob Storage`, my pipeline has two activities 1. `Copy Activity` (copy file from `ADLS` to `Blob`) 2.`Custom .NET Activity` (delete files from `ADLS`).

Now `ADF` is scheduled perfectly and running smoothly with no errors - `Copy Activity` is all fine and able to see files copied to `Blob`. My issue is with the `Custom .NET Activity`- no errors are being logged (I am using `IActivityLogger logger`) but the files are not being deleted. So, I started to debug by `ADL .NET SDK code` part and faced the below issue -

> Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.Models.AdlsErrorException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2146233088
>     Message=Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
>     Source=Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store
>     StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.FileSystemOperations.d__28.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.FileSystemOperationsExtensions.d__39.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.FileSystemOperationsExtensions.Delete(IFileSystemOperations operations, String accountName, String filePath, Nullable'1 recursive)
>          at DataLakeApplication.DotNetADLApplication.ADLApplication(List'1 dataSetsToDelete) in C:\Projects\C#\DataLakeApplication\DataLakeApplication\Program.cs:line 117
>     InnerException:

Code Snippet of `delete` operation:

```
var fileDeleterResult =
_adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Delete(_adlsAccountName, strInputToDelete, null);
```

I am using `AAD Service Principal`in my .NET code to communicate with `ADLS`, authentication part is ok and even I have tried couple of other `FileSystemOperations` `ListFileStatus` & `GetFileStatus` - these works fine. Only my `Delete` is throwing the above error, so I thought to check back on the permissions to `ADLS` for my `Service Principal` which is given `Owner`- role and `RWX` permission to the `ADLS` folders.

Any lead would be much appreciated and do let me know if any further information would be required on this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to solve it, my mistake basically I was trying to pass `Azure Data Lake` folder path instead of the file path which was giving me the `Forbidden` error message.
The code that I implemented to delete files inside a folder -

```
foreach (string strInputToDelete in dataSetsToDelete)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Listing files and directories.");
   var itemList = _adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.ListFileStatus(_adlsAccountName, strInputToDelete).FileStatuses.FileStatus.ToList();
   var fileMenuItems = itemList.Select(a => String.Format("{0,15} {1}", a.Type, a.PathSuffix));
   Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", fileMenuItems));
   Console.WriteLine("Files and directories listed.");

   for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; i++)
   {
        Console.WriteLine("Deleting files...");
        var fileDeleteResult =_adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Delete(_adlsAccountName, strInputToDelete + itemList[i].PathSuffix);
        Console.WriteLine("Deletion result: " + fileDeleteResult.OperationResult.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Files deleted");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed some funny business with permissions in ADLS.

A few things to double check:

If you haven't done already (I'm sure you have) have another read of:

[Access control in Azure Data Lake Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-access-control)

Paying close attention to the non cascading nature of permissions and how masks work.

However as you said the user has Owner permission, which should mean all mighty powerful.

Try to reapply the permissions including the children (if applicable to your security model), to see if that fixes things.

I also wonder whether [data lake diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-diagnostic-logs) may find something (I'm not sure, I've not looked at it myself).

Comment: Thanks @Alex for your insights. Indeed I have tried the access control on ADLS but to no avail. Did all the redo/reapply nothing worked even gave full-blown access to `EveryOne Else` that too didn't click (hoped it won't). Coming to the Diagnostic part I also have not looked/worked on that yet, will have a go at it.